# Rstudio construction of table

Tags: r

I am learning rstudio for the first time and I have a question in organizing information in a table,

I have three variable, sex(0=man, 1=woman) BP(blood pressure) and Obese, in total I have 102 observations. In the obese variable, values above 1 means you are obese, less than 1 means you are healthy.

I want to construct a table that tells me in one column the number of women that are obese and healthy and in another column the number of man that are obese and healthy.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Using the iris dataset:

```
library(dplyr) # Load package

iris %>% # Take the data
  mutate(above_value = if_else(Sepal.Width > 3, "Above", "Below")) %>% # create an toy variable similar to your obese variable
  count(Species, above_value) # Count by Species (or gender in your case) and the variable I created above

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Species    above_value     n
  <fct>      <chr>       <int>
1 setosa     Above          42
2 setosa     Below           8
3 versicolor Above           8
4 versicolor Below          42
5 virginica  Above          17
6 virginica  Below          33
```

Answer (score 1):

if your object is called `data` with columns `sex`, `BP` and `Obese`:

```
library(dplyr)
summary <- data %>%
  group_by(sex) %>%
  summarise(count_obese = sum(ifelse(Obese > 1, TRUE, FALSE), na.rm = TRUE),
            count_healthy = sum(ifelse(Obese <= 1, TRUE, FALSE), na.rm = TRUE))
```

`sum` works as R equates the value `TRUE` to `1` and `FALSE` to `0`. For example:

```
> TRUE + FALSE + TRUE
[1] 2
```